# Why can't flex item with no-wrap child shrink?

Tags: css, flexbox

The flex item(item-2) has a no-wrap child (long) with long content.

As far as I know, flex-shrink should kick in when flex items exceed parent(box)'s width.

Could anyone explain why.

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
}

.item-2 {
  flex: 1 1 10000px;
}

.long {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="item-1">left</div>
  <div class="item-2">
    <div class="long">
      long content - long content - long content - long content - long content long content - long content - long content - long content - long content long content - long content - long content - long content - long content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: min-width:0 to item2

Answer (score 1):

Flex, not shrink because of `white-space: nowrap` rule in `long` class.

*A flex item cannot be smaller than the size of its content along the main axis.*